# AWS Cost Explorer data mismatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using python boto3 scripts to get some cost related metrics from AWS Cost Explorer api which is running every morning 01:00 am to get yesterday's metric.  When I see the metric data it shows incorrect values comparing it with the Cost Explorer dashboard.

Ex. 1:00 AM - REGION us-west-2 unblended-cost 10$ (Incorrect)
    10:00 AM - REGION us-west-2 unblended-cost 14$ (Correct)

So to fix it I run the script again like in the evening time it will get the correct data from the CE.  The timestamps which comes in the response is same for both in the morning and evening which is yesterday's date.

I have checked if I am getting any NextPageToken which is not coming and tried running it on different hours from which I can see that after a particular time correct data start coming.  Like after 8 am or 10 am or 11 am etc.

Comment: HI Mayank, I'm having the same issue. Have you found the reason behind this?

Comment: Right now I am running the script after 1 day to get yesterday's data

Answer (score 0):

cost per your usage will be available up to previous day also some data might be updated after 24 hours. e.g Today is 6th May so available cost is till 5th May.

[Check here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-exploring-data.html)